# Maven dependency chain with same version number

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have a relatively large maven project with a module dependency chain, and I am trying to automate a build process via Jenkins that uploads module jar files with a version number.  While doing this, I would still like modules have a default version number (default to 0.0.0.dev) if no arguments are specified to the command line maven call.

I first tried `<version>0.0.0.dev</version>` figuring that I could override this value with a maven command line.  This turns out to not be the case: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MINSTALL-30.  There is a comment that lead me to my next try: `<version>${build.number}</version>` where I would pass in the build number to the command line.  Obviously, because the property isn’t set anywhere else, if no build number was supplied, I’d get jars such as module.name-${build.number}.jar.  Simple fix: as the comment suggested, add `<properties><build.number>0.0.0.dev</build.number></properties>`.

This causes a transitive problem when I try to propagate that version to module dependencies. Suppose that I have moduleA depends on moduleB depends on moduleC, where I require each to have the same version number. Example of dependency: In moduleA's pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>groupID</groupId>
    <artifactId>moduleB</artifactId>
    <version>${version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Running `mvn compile –Dbuild.number=9.9.9.9` on moduleA: it will look for moduleB-9.9.9.9.jar, but it will look for moduleC-0.0.0.dev.jar. This is because the build.number property is not transitive (unlike the actual version number).

My question: how can I get the desired behavior? With no additional arguments passed at command line, build a jar with a default version number, but allow that default value to be overridden in a way that the module will for my other modules with that same version.

Comment: Module and Dependency have very specific meanings in Maven. Properties on the command line ***will propagate*** to all modules being built in the current reactor. Is `moduleB` a dependency and a module of `ModuleA` or just a dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not propagate properties in to the pom of a dependency with one exception. For all intents and purposes the pom of a dependency is fixed at the time it was installed/deployed in to your local/remote repository. If the dependency is being resolved via the reactor (i.e. the dependency is being built as part of the current build) then command-line properties will propagate to that dependencies pom as it is being built.